# Find the radius of convergence of a power series.

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, convergence-divergence

Consider the power series $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^n$$ where $a_0=0$ and $a_n=\frac{\sin(n!)}{n!}$ for  $n≥1$

Let $R$ be the radius of convergence then

1. $R≥1$
2. $R≥2π$
3. $R≥π$

My attempt: I used the formula for

$$
\frac{1}{R}=\lim\frac{(a_{n+1})}{a_n}\\
=\lim\frac{\sin((n+1)!)}{(n+1)!}\frac{n!}{\sin(n!)}\\
=\lim\frac{\sin((n+1)!)}{(n+1)\sin(n!)}
$$
now I am unable to proceed further, I thought much about to evaluate the limit but can't get it, so any hint or solution will be helpful,

Thanks in advance

Comment: The ratio test is often not applicable. You can use the root test (the Cauchy-Hadamard formula).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An idea: for **any** $\;x\in\Bbb R\;$

$$\left|\frac{\sin n!}{n!}x^n\right|\le\frac{|x|^n}{n!}$$

and now apply Weierstrass's M-Test.

Comment: Weierstrass M? I would just say since $\sum |x|^n/n! < \infty$ for all $x,$ the given power series converges absolutely for all $x,$ hence its ROC = $\infty.$

Comment: @Timbuc  : Weierstrass's M-Test tells about uniform convergence, then how can i conclude the answer..!! which is about radius of convergence

Comment: @zhw : Then all the three options are correct? we can't calculate the above limit?

Comment: Well,  zhw has a point: no need of Weierstrass here. The convergence radius is $\;\infty\;$ .

Comment: @Chiranjeev Yes, $\infty$ is larger than all three of those numbers.

Comment: @zhw. - you could have added  $\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^\infty |x|^n/n! = \exp(|x|)$ to reinforce your point

Answer (score 1):

Root test

$\frac{1}{R}$ = lim$|\frac{sin(n!)}{(n!)}|^\frac{1}{n}$

$≤$ lim$(\frac{1}{(n!)})^\frac{1}{n}$ = $0$, as $0<(\frac{1}{(n!)})<1$

which gives, $R$ = ∞. Tell me It's right or wrong??

Comment: Well $1/n < 1,$ but $(1/n)^{1/n} \to 1.$ Incidentally, you can't just plop down $1/R = \lim |a_n|^{1/n}$ becuse the limit might not exist. You can, however, plop down $\limsup.$

Comment: @zhw yeah you are right.. we can't plop down. But now i am confused as according to you we are getting limit 1, so radius of convergence will be 1 then none of the option will be true..!! Please clear my confusion, Thanx

Comment: I'm just saying that $0<b_n<1$ doesn't imply $b_n^{1/n} \to 0.$